# Using KDE starter to start application via ssh

Tags: kde, remote, kde4

I would like to start VirtualBox on my server using the command `ssh -X server virtualbox`. This works well from a shell and asks for a login password as intended. I tried to create a KDE 4 "application starter" which executes this command. Unfortunately, the starter does not recognize the need to type a password.

Is there an intended way to fire up a remote application from KDE?